# JSON key has '#' Special character

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

Currently I need the URL for an image and I am getting it through the JSON file. I am not sure to acquire the key that has the URL due to the key having a `#` at the start. Here is the JSON:

```
{  
 "#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/3ed37777196a6f2c29c02a1a58a93e4d.png",
 "size":"small"
},
{  
 "#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/3ed37777196a6f2c29c02a1a58a93e4d.png",
 "size":"medium"
}
```

Comment: `json['#text']`?

Comment: What do you expect instead of `#text` ?

Comment: it does not matter since it is a string

Comment: and if you want to remove # from the keys you can do data.map(x=>({"text":x['#text'], "size":x.size}))

Comment: Obviously you can't use `arr[0].#text`, since that's not a legal character, so use the array key access syntax: `arr[0]['#text']`

Comment: I need the string from #text but # is not a valid character

Answer (score 6):

Same as with every other time you encounter some JSON string!

The `#` is an invalid character in a property name, work around is the bracket notation: `«object»[property]` --> `«array»[index]['#text']`.

We can use `forEach` to extract the results.

```js
var string = '[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/3ed37777196a6f2c29c02a1a58a93e4d.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/3ed37777196a6f2c29c02a1a58a93e4d.png","size":"medium"}]';

var parsed = JSON.parse(string);

//parsed is an array, we can loop over it
parsed.forEach(function(obj) {
      console.log(obj['#text']);
});
```

Even prettier would be if you can select from the array based on size:

```js
var string = '[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/3ed37777196a6f2c29c02a1a58a93e4d.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/3ed37777196a6f2c29c02a1a58a93e4d.png","size":"medium"}]';

function getImageUrlBySize(size, json) {
  var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed.find(function(element) { //modern browsers only (no IE)
      return element['size'] == size;
  })['#text']; //add text here since find returns the full item
}

console.log(getImageUrlBySize('small', string));
```

Comment: I am also using last fm api. currently I have a few songs that Im looping through and how would I get that string that was previously stated from the object?